# Storing footnotes related to fields

Tags: mysql, normalization

Take the following (straightforward) transaction table for stock trades:

```
Trade date | Shares | Price | Commission | Total amt

2/11/2013  | 100    | $10   | $10        | $1000
```

etc.

Let's say that I wanted to store footnote-like comment(s) on all of these fields. Are there any best-practices for this kind of storage?

I was thinking of two options:

1) Add extra fields in the transactions table -- one per primary value -- that would store comment ids in plain text, perhaps separated by a bar (|), and then parse through them at runtime. This solution doesn't allow for joins, but would preserve the transaction list in a more normal fashion.

2) Change the table from transactions to something more like a name-value storage, where I could then have footnotes placed into a related table, with the usual lookup table between them. This solution allows for joins, but could be slow to produce results, and isn't very human-readable. Incidentally, the name-value table would look more like this:

```
Item | Value | FootnoteId

Date|2/11/2013|22

Shares|100|0

Price|$10|24
```

etc.

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: "more normal fashion"? storing formatted data in a db field is abnormal. a normal design would split the comments into their own sub-table. hence the process being called "normalization".

Comment: @MarcB: I didn't make it clear, but comments/footnotes will go into a sub-table. The question is more about how to design the primary table to link it with comments-per-field.